# PHP websocket server and mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, websocket

I have a php websocket server based on [this one](http://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/). This websocket server runs on a different apache than the public webserver but on the same physical server so I need a database connection to retrieve userdata. The userdata is fetched by the current session id which is also updated in the database when a user loggs in. Now, if I run my websocket server it works perfect but after a decent time (can't say a timespan) the result stays empty. I checked the dataset.

The querystring is up to date and the correct session id is in the database which should return the desired row but the result stays empty. If I kill the process and run this websocket server, it will work for the time being but after a while the result is empty again.

This is my websocketserver.php simplified:

```
set_time_limit(0);
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

$db1 = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'dev', 'xxxxxxxx' );
mysql_select_db('cb_dev',$db1);

function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
    global $Server;

    $sessionid = "/*just imagine a session id here*/";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, id FROM users WHERE sessionid = '$sessionid'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
}

function wsOnOpen($clientID) {
    //
}

function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
    //
}

$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');

$Server->wsStartServer('0.0.0.0', 9010);
```

Note: The used session id is served correctly so this is not the problem.

Comment: Can you post the code that updates the session id when the user loggs in?

Answer (score 3):

[Swoole](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src) is a better choice for your requirement.
It support native websocket server & async mysql  in PHP ,with a c extension

WebSocket Server example:

```
$ws = new swoole_websocket_server("0.0.0.0", 9502);

$ws->on('open', function ($ws, $request) {
    var_dump($request->fd, $request->get, $request->server);
    $ws->push($request->fd, "hello, welcome\n");
});

$ws->on('message', function ($ws, $frame) {
    echo "Message: {$frame->data}\n";
    $ws->push($frame->fd, "server: {$frame->data}");
});

$ws->on('close', function ($ws, $fd) {
    echo "client-{$fd} is closed\n";
});

$ws->start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your $sessionid was expired. Need to set higher timeout:

```
// 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
session_set_cookie_params(3600);
```